# Obtener datos desde MySQL a JTextField Java

Tags: java, mysql, sql

Estoy intentando obtener datos desde mi db y mostrarlos en TextField's, mi problema es que solo se obtiene los valores de la primera tabla en mi lista, al seleccionar la segunda, estos no se actualizan

*Lo cargo mediante MouseClick*

Este es el primer campo seleccionado, cargan sus valores completos
[image: Primer campo Seleccionado]

Y esto sucede al intentar cargar el segundo item en la lista

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Solo cambian los valores que estan visibles en las filas de la tabla, los demas no, sin embargo si tengo datos en mi db

*Tabla Autor*
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

*Tabla Encargado*
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A continuación inserto el código de la forma que intento llamar los valores, agradecería que me corrigieran la forma correcta de hacerlo

```
private void tableMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                   
    try {
        String temporalgenero = "";
        String temporaltecnica = "";
        String tempencargado = "";

        int fila = table.getSelectedRow();
        String id = (String) table.getValueAt(fila, 0);
        String rutautor = (String) table.getValueAt(fila, 1);
        String tecnica = (String) table.getValueAt(fila, 2);
        String genero = (String) table.getValueAt(fila, 3);
        String resultdate = (String) table.getValueAt(fila, 4);
        String nombrep = (String) table.getValueAt(fila, 5);
        String tamaño = (String) table.getValueAt(fila, 6);
        String ubicacion = (String) table.getValueAt(fila, 7);

        idpintura1.setText(id);
        aidi.setText(id);
        rut_a.setText(rutautor);
        año_c_arte.setText(resultdate);
        nombre_arte.setText(nombrep);
        tamaño_arte.setText(tamaño);
        nombre_sala.setText(ubicacion);

        switch (tecnica) {
            case "101":
                temporaltecnica = "Oleo";
                break;
            case "102":
                temporaltecnica = "Puntillismo";
                break;
            case "103":
                temporaltecnica = "Acuarela";
                break;
            case "104":
                temporaltecnica = "Fresco";
                break;
            case "105":
                temporaltecnica = "Temple";
                break;
            case "Null - No Definido":
                temporaltecnica = "Seleccione una opción";
                break;
        }

        tecnica_arte.setSelectedItem(temporaltecnica);

        switch (genero) {
            case "201":
                temporalgenero = "Desnudo";
                break;
            case "202":
                temporalgenero = "Retrato";
                break;
            case "203":
                temporalgenero = "Naturaleza Muerta";
                break;
            case "204":
                temporalgenero = "Pintura Paisajista";
                break;
            case "205":
                temporalgenero = "Pintura Histórica";
                break;
            case "Null - No Definido":
                temporalgenero = "Seleccione una opción";
                break;
        }

        genero_arte.setSelectedItem(temporalgenero);

        String sql1 = "Select * FROM examenjava.autor WHERE DNI = " + rutautor + ";";

        accesoADatos.Conexion cn = new accesoADatos.Conexion();
        cn.ejecuta(sql1);
        ResultSet autorrs = cn.consultaautor(sql1);


        while (autorrs.next()) {

            String nombreautor = autorrs.getString("NOMBRE");
            String apellidoautor = autorrs.getString("APELLIDO");
            String nacioautor = autorrs.getString("NACIONALIDAD");

            nombre_autor.setText(nombreautor);
            apellido_a.setText(apellidoautor);
            nacionalidad_a.setText(nacioautor);

        }


        accesoADatos.Conexion cc = new accesoADatos.Conexion();
        String sql3 = "Select * FROM examenjava.sala WHERE CODIGO_SALA = " + ubicacion + ";";
        ResultSet salars = cc.consultasala(sql3);

        while (salars.next()) {

            String clamps = salars.getString("CANTIDAD_LAMPARAS");
            String tempsala = salars.getString("TEMPERATURA");
            String cierresala = salars.getString("CIERRE_CENTRALIZADO");
            String alarmasala = salars.getString("ALARMA_INCENDIO");

            tempencargado = salars.getString("ENCARGADO");

            lamps_sala.setText(clamps);
            temp_sala.setText(tempsala);
            cierre_c_sala.setSelectedItem(cierresala);
            alarma_incendio_sala.setSelectedItem(alarmasala);

        }
        salars.close();
        accesoADatos.Conexion cx = new accesoADatos.Conexion();
        String sql2 = "Select * FROM examenjava.encargado WHERE DNI = " + tempencargado + ";";
        ResultSet encargadors = cx.consultaencargado(sql2);
        while (encargadors.next()) {

            //String dniencargado = encargadors.getString("DNI");
            String nombreencargado = encargadors.getString("NOMBRE");
            String profesionencargado = encargadors.getString("PROFESION");
            String añoencargado = encargadors.getString("AÑO_INGRESO");

            rut_encargado.setText(tempencargado);
            nombre_encargado.setText(nombreencargado);
            prof_encargado.setText(profesionencargado);
            año_in_encargado.setText(añoencargado);

        }
        encargadors.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

Me falto agregar, esta es la clase donde gestiono las conexiones

```
public void ejecuta(String sql) throws SQLException {
    try {
        instruc.execute(sql);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}

public ResultSet consultaautor(String sql) throws SQLException {
    rs = instruc.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM  autor");
    return rs;
}

public ResultSet consultaencargado(String sql) throws SQLException {
    rs = instruc.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM  encargado");
    return rs;
}

public ResultSet consultasala(String sql) throws SQLException {
    rs = instruc.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM  sala");
    return rs;
}

public ResultSet consultaobraarte(String sql) throws SQLException {
    rs = instruc.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM  obra_arte");
    return rs;
}

public ResultSet consultaini() throws SQLException {
    rs = instruc.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM  obra_arte");
    return rs;
}

public ResultSet consultagenero() throws SQLException {
    rs = instruc.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM  genero");
    return rs;
}

public ResultSet consultatecnica() throws SQLException {
    rs = instruc.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM  tecnica");
    return rs;
}
```

Comment: No se entiende cuál es el problema en sí. ¿Qué quieres decir con esto: *Solo cambian los valores que estan visibles en las filas de la tabla, los demas no*... ¿qué son *los demás*? ¿Cuando deberían cambiar, al hacer clic donde? Mientras más claro seas podrás recibir una ayuda de mayor calidad.

Comment: @A. Cedano en la Jtable estan los valores id, autor, tecnica, genero etc, que son la primary key de mis tablas en mi db, si te fijas en las  dos primeras imagenes al momento de enviarlas al formulario solo se actualizan esos datos, los valores en Datos Autor, Encargado sala y Ubicación no se actualizan, los textfield mantienen los valores del primer seleccionado, sin embargo si actualiza los valores de la tabla (ID autor tecnica genero año creacion, etc)

Comment: No-respuesta: yo comenzaría haciendo una inicialización de campos en el método relacionado con el cambio de selección en la tabla. Que todo comience vacío para que no quede con datos viejos si los nuevos están vacíos o incompletos (no sé qué campos puedas permitir nulos, etc). Lo otro: yo pondría la tabla arriba por usabilidad. Lo otro: una pena que no sigas dejando las consultas separadas de la lógica del panel, porque igual estás construyendo las consultas SQL en el panel

Comment: QUé tipo de dato es el DNI?